# Como pegar o valor máximo de uma lista circular Java?

Tags: java, lista

Como eu posso obter o valor máximo de uma lista circular que utilize um nó sentinela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina uma variável para conter o maior valor iniciando com [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE) e percorra a lista a partir da sentinela elemento por elemento até chegar de volta na sentinela (ou então ao invés de `Long.MIN_VALUE`, você pode usar o próprio valor da sentinela). Sempre que encontrar um valor maior que o que tem nessa variável, você faz a atribuição.

Exemplo sem usar `Long.MIN_VALUE` quando o valor da sentinela é usável. Neste exemplo aliás, você nem precisa de sentinela:

```
public class No {
    private No proximo;
    private long valor;

    // getters, setters e outros métodos.

    public long maiorValor() {
        long maior = valor;
        for (No p = proximo; p != this; p = p.proximo) {
            if (p.valor > maior) maior = p.valor;
        }
        return maior;
    }
}
```

Exemplo usando `Long.MIN_VALUE` quando o valor da sentinela não é usável:

```
public class No {
    private No proximo;
    private long valor; // Não deve ser usado se este nó for a sentinela.

    // getters, setters e outros métodos.
}

public class ListaCircular {
     private No sentinela;

    // getters, setters e outros métodos.

    public long maiorValor() {
        long maior = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        for (No p = sentinela.getProximo(); p != sentinela; p = p.getProximo()) {
            int v = p.getValor();
            if (v > maior) maior = v;
        }
        return maior;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você teria algum exemplo de código? Eu entendi a explicação, mas não estou conseguindo executar...

Comment: @Pedro Editado.